# Validation with scenario not working Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

The idea here is to insert in two different tables parameters using SCENARIO, first register the customer with their parameters and then register the order that belongs to a customer, all in just one form.

I'm sending a form with several parameters, some will be used in the insertion of a customer using scenario, and the other parameters I will use in order (I did this so I do not have to create two forms) the parameters are being correctly sent through POST together with the csrf.

```
public function createOrder()
{
    //$customer = Customer::find()->where(['email' => $params->email])->limit(1)->asArray()->all();
    $customer = new Customer;
    $customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $customer->scenario = 'create';
    if($customer->validate()){
        $customer->save();
        vdp($customer);
    } else{
        vdpd($customer->getErrors());
    }

    die;

}
```

This returns me an array saying that the Name, email, address, cell, phone, city, etc parameters *can not be left blank*.

In my customer model:

```
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';

public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['name', 'email', 'public_place', 'cell_phone', 'phone', 'city', 'cep', 'state', 'neighborhood', 'number', 'complement'];
    return $scenarios;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreateOrder()
{
   $customer = new Customer;
   $customer->setScenario(Customer::SCENARIO_CREATE);
   if($customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
      if($customer->save()){
          vdp($customer);
      } else {
          vdpd($customer->getErrors());
      }
   }
   die;
}
```

**MODEL**

```
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';

public function rules()
{
    return [
       [['name', 'email', 'address'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE], // Add more required fields on 'create' scenario.
       ... // some more rules
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['name', 'email', 'public_place', 'cell_phone', 'phone', 'city', 'cep', 'state', 'neighborhood', 'number', 'complement'];
    return $scenarios;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend!

Comment: Where is `validate()` method call?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase in `$customer->save()`, first it will validate the form.

Answer (score 1):

1) `createOrder()` should be `actionCreateOrder()` in controller, not in model.

2)

```
$customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
$customer->scenario = 'create';
if ($customer->validate()) {
...
```

should be

```
$customer->scenario = Customer::SCENARIO_CREATE;
if ($customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $customer->validate()) { ... }
```

Because `load` method loads attributes for the current scenario and there is no need to run validation before the model is loaded. See the [example](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#actions).

3) Declare [rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#declaring-rules) for your attributes in `Customer` model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `$scenario` before `load()` call. Scenario defines attributes, that can be set by `load()`, so you're doing it too late and it has no effect. Try this:

```
$customer = new Customer;
$customer->scenario = 'create';
$customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

Comment: Hello, this did not working. Keep falling on the else and saying that the fields can not be left blank.

Comment: Then it looks like your POST data is missing, probably your form is incorrect.